# parse issue:Expected unqualified-id and semantic issue:C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

Tags: c++

It's quite funny that it keeps f'ing me while I've put everything right.!

It keeps giving me same issues all the time and I can't figure out what's going on anymore. I'm like so done, I've rewritten everything and still all kinds of errors keep popping up. I know that this is part of the programming that you can't just succeed all at once, you always have at some point struggle for hours with random kinds of errors. I was wishing I could get response from someone who've seen this before, as I'm quite inpatient person, I get fed-up quite easily by stuff like this, especially when I'm starting up at something like this.

```
    // This program demonstrates the xor() function.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool xor(bool a, bool b);

int main()
{
    bool p, q;

    cout << "Enter P (0 or 1): ";
    cin >> p;
    cout << "Enter Q (0 or 1): ";
    cin >> q;

    cout << "P AND Q: " << (p && q) << '\n';
    cout << "P OR Q; " << (p || q) << '\n';
    cout << "P XOR Q: " << xor(p, q) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
bool xor  (bool a = bool b)
{
    return (a || b) && !(a && b);
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MBzd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xor` is not allowed as an identifier, it is an [alternative token](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) for `^`.

Comment: Mind showing me an example how is it correctly done then? Appreciated.

Comment: @user4905689 Just use any other (allowed) identifier, like `my_xor`.

Comment: Did not know that. Crom! You might have saved me some several minutes of future hell.

Comment: @user4581301 You would be surprised at the number of experienced C++ programmers who are not aware of the alternate tokens, so don't be ashamed.